# Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] unable get customer incoming IP address

Tags: c#, networking, model-view-controller, ip

I'm using ["REMOTE_ADDR"] to get each log-in customer's incoming IP address, to store in our database for the record.

However, the ["REMOTE_ADDR"] shows some discrepancy behavior, with most of the time only being able to get back our own default gateway IP address.

The code snippet of getting incoming IP address to our server is pretty straight forward (in _viewstart.html):

```
string customerIP =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerIP))
customerIP  = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

I track the server traffic to check the incoming IP address, and I find out that the incoming IP address from our customer is the correct public IP address, but I have no idea why my function is unable to capture the correct IP address.

P.S. Sometimes, the code ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] can capture some correct public IP addresses, but most of the time just returned the default gateway IP address. So I'm quite confused whether it is a source code problem or server setting issue. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: When proxies are involved, the `X-Forwarded-For` header is generally what you'll need to inspect to get the original client IP address: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: Hi @Martin Costello , thanks for your reply. My bad that I do not include all related code (I did edit my question now). Actually I had use ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] as well , before using ["REMOTE_ADDR"], since X Forward always return null, so I just skip it .